# GNU Assembler (Mac OS X 64-bit): Illegal instruction: 4

Tags: macos, assembly, x86-64, system-calls, gnu-assembler

I am new to GNU Assembler and I'm trying to execute this piece of code:

```
.globl _main
_main:
    movl $1, %eax
    movl $0, %ebx
    int $0x80
```

This programm should exit by the system call exit (`1`). Compiled it (no warnings):

```
gcc test.s
```

But running it gives me the error: `Illegal instruction: 4`

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're compiling a 64-bit executable, then you should write something like this:

```
movq $0x2000001, %rax
movq $0, %rdi
syscall
```

[Source](http://thexploit.com/secdev/mac-os-x-64-bit-assembly-system-calls/).

Comment: Right, I've just noticed that it runs if I compile for 32-bit. Thanks!