# basic assembly not working on Mac (x86_64+Lion)?

Tags: macos, assembly, x86-64, system-calls

here is the code(exit.s):

```
.section .data,
.section .text,
.globl _start
_start:
    movl $1, %eax
    movl $32, %ebx
    syscall
```

when I execute `" as exit.s -o exit.o && ld exit.o -o exit -e _start && ./exit"`

the return is "Bus error: 10" and the output of "`echo $?`" is 138

I also tried the example of the correct answer in this question: [Process command line in Linux 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730064/process-command-line-in-linux-64-bit)

stil get "bus error"...

Comment: possible duplicate of [GNU Assembler (Mac OS X 64-bit): Illegal instruction: 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178313/gnu-assembler-mac-os-x-64-bit-illegal-instruction-4)

Comment: Also [How to get this simple assembly to run?](//stackoverflow.com/a/34191324) is a new duplicate that also explains how to make OS X system calls.  I'm not sure if one answer is better / more useful than the other.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First, you are using old 32-bit Linux kernel calling convention on Mac OS X - this absolutely doesn't work.

Second, syscalls in Mac OS X are structured in a different way - they all have a leading class identifier *and* a syscall number. The class can be Mach, BSD or something else (see [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1699.26.8/osfmk/mach/i386/syscall_sw.h) in the XNU source) and is shifted 24 bits to the left. Normal BSD syscalls have class `2` and thus begin from `0x2000000`. Syscalls in class `0` are *invalid*.

As per §A.2.1 of the [SysV AMD64 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf), also followed by Mac OS X, syscall id (together with its class on XNU!) goes to `%rax` (or to `%eax` as the high 32 bits are unused on XNU). The fist argument goes in `%rdi`. Next goes to `%rsi`. And so on. `%rcx` is used by the kernel and its value is destroyed and that's why all functions in `libc.dyld` save it into `%r10` before making syscalls (similarly to the `kernel_trap` macro from `syscall_sw.h`).

Third, code sections in Mach-O binaries are called `__text` and not `.text` as in Linux ELF and also reside in the `__TEXT` segment, collectively referred as `(__TEXT,__text)` (`nasm` automatically translates `.text` as appropriate if Mach-O is selected as target object type) - see the [Mac OS X ABI Mach-O File Format Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/MachORuntime/Reference/reference.html). Even if you get the assembly instructions right, putting them in the wrong segment/section leads to bus error. You can either use the `.section __TEXT,__text` directive (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/developertools/Reference/Assembler/040-Assembler_Directives/asm_directives.html) for directive syntax) or you can also use the (simpler) `.text` directive, or you can drop it altogether since it is assumed if no `-n` option was supplied to `as` (see the manpage of `as`).

Fourth, the default entry point for the Mach-O `ld` is called `start` (although, as you've already figured it out, it can be changed via the `-e` linker option).

Given all the above you should modify your assembler source to read as follows:

```
; You could also add one of the following directives for completeness
; .text
; or
; .section __TEXT,__text

.globl start
start:
    movl $0x2000001, %eax
    movl $32, %edi
    syscall
```

Here it is, working as expected:

```
$ as -o exit.o exit.s; ld -o exit exit.o
$ ./exit; echo $?
32
```

Comment: thanks for the help!  could I use -arch i386 to make the 32-bit assembly program works?  I tried it but get "Illegal instruction: 4". just like the question referred by Alex ,"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178313/gnu-assembler-mac-os-x-64-bit-illegal-instruction-4"   I am not sure how to I compile it for 32-bit

Comment: `syscall` is not a valid 32-bit instruction. And the `int $0x80` i386 syscalls use BSD style arguments passing via the stack. See [here](http://osxbook.com/blog/2009/03/15/crafting-a-tiny-mach-o-executable/) or dive [here](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/bsd/dev/i386/systemcalls.c?v=xnu-1699.24.8#L92).

Answer (score 4):

Adding more explanation on the magic number. I made the same mistake by applying the Linux syscall number to my NASM.

From the xnu kernel sources in [osfmk/mach/i386/syscall_sw.h](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-792.13.8/osfmk/mach/i386/syscall_sw.h) (search `SYSCALL_CLASS_SHIFT`).

```c
/*
 * Syscall classes for 64-bit system call entry.
 * For 64-bit users, the 32-bit syscall number is partitioned
 * with the high-order bits representing the class and low-order
 * bits being the syscall number within that class.
 * The high-order 32-bits of the 64-bit syscall number are unused.
 * All system classes enter the kernel via the syscall instruction.
```

Syscalls are partitioned:

```c
#define SYSCALL_CLASS_NONE  0   /* Invalid */
#define SYSCALL_CLASS_MACH  1   /* Mach */  
#define SYSCALL_CLASS_UNIX  2   /* Unix/BSD */
#define SYSCALL_CLASS_MDEP  3   /* Machine-dependent */
#define SYSCALL_CLASS_DIAG  4   /* Diagnostics */
```

As we can see, the tag for BSD system calls is 2. So that magic number *0x2000000* is constructed as:

```c
// 2 << 24
#define SYSCALL_CONSTRUCT_UNIX(syscall_number) \
            ((SYSCALL_CLASS_UNIX << SYSCALL_CLASS_SHIFT) | \
             (SYSCALL_NUMBER_MASK & (syscall_number)))
```

Why it uses BSD tag in the end, probably Apple switches from `mach` kernel to `BSD` kernel. Historical reason.

Inspired by the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53905561/5335565).